# Django, MySQL, and Cloud9

Tags: python, mysql, django, cloud9-ide

I am trying to connect to my MYSQL database in my Django project on Cloud9 (c9.io).

At first I have started my database by entering `mysql-ctl start` in the console which works all fine. If I'm entering it again I get the message `MySQL already running`.

In `settings.py` I've updated `DATABASES` to the following:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'c9',
        'USER': 'my_username',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    },
}
```

but when I'm running `python manage.py syncdb` it results in the error `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")`.

What am I doing wrong? I've read that HOST and PORT should be left empty in order to obtain the default values.

Answer (score 1):

Acording to [the documentation](https://docs.c9.io/setting_up_mysql.html) you should connect to the database with following parameters:

```
Hostname  $IP       The same local IP as the application you run on Cloud9
Port      3306      The default MySQL port number
User      $C9_USER  Your Cloud9 user name
```

So try to add `HOST`/`PORT` values to the `DATABASES` setting:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'c9',
        'USER': 'my_username',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'my_ip',
        'PORT': '3306',
    },
}
```

Comment: Host / Port need to be swapped, and maybe suggest using `os.environ["IP"]` and `os.environ["C9_USER"]`

Comment: Oops, my bad.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `'HOST'`:`'127.0.0.1'`

```
   'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'USER': 'user_naeme',
        'NAME':'c9',
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm already have this problem and >> solved 
you should add your Host name 
e.g

```
'HOST': 'your_username.mysql.your_Host_name.com'
```

example my host is 'pythonanywhere-services.com'
finally

```
DATABASES = {    'default': {
  'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
  'NAME': 'dataBaseName',
  'USER': 'urUser',
  'PASSWORD': 'urPass',
  'HOST': 'urUser.mysql.your_Host_name.com',    } }
```